# Create job only if you are login Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When you click on `create`, it redirects to the next page.
If the user is logged in, redirects it to `jobs/create`, and if it is not to `/login`.

```
<a href="jobs/create"><h3>Create</h3></a>
```

What would an ***if statement*** look like in this case?

Comment: add `auth` middleware to `jobs/create` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like

```
<a href="@auth /jobs/create @else /login @endauth"><h3>Create</h3></a>
```

Comment: This would only print out the right route, but the route itself would still be accessible to the not-authorized user.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an if statement. Laravel has built in middleware to detect if a user is authenticated, and redirects them to the login if they are not.

Either add the Auth middleware to your route like this:

```
Route::get('create', 'JobController@create')->middleware('auth');
```

Or add it to a constructor function at the top of your controller to exclude anyone who isn't logged in from accessing any of the functions:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes